# Lilvati as a good source to learn math.

Tags: self-learning, math-history

I usually like Sanskrit text and reading their literature I am wondering if I can reinforce my math skills with this ancient Lilvati text it goes over the basics, but I find it may be handy, yet I don't know if there are any errors in regards to it's formulas and methods.

Comment: here are the slides for a talk about your book, in English. https://www.uou.ac.in/lecturenotes/science/MSCMT-19/lilavati.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Those slides are fascinating, thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks yall very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that reading that Sanskrit text is a good way to learn modern mathematics, even when it covers modern material without errors. If you know a modern way to do something you might really enjoy figuring out how that compares to the way it's done in the ancient text. That should reinforce both the mathematics and your Sanskrit skills.